# A double staric pointer (**p) as two dimensional array

Tags: pointers

I know that a single staric pointer like *p can be used as a one dimensional array. But how can I use a double staric pointer like **p as two dimensional array?

Comment: What does "staric" mean? Also, language are you referring to?

Comment: staric mean '*', like single staric is *p and double staric is **p. I am referring C and C++.

Comment: Then you should add those language tags to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `**p` as an array of one-dimensional arrays.

`p[i]` is i-th element of one-dimensional array. But your array is array of arrays. So `p[i]` is array. `p[i][j]` then is an element of your two-dimensional array.

You can initialize `p` with code like this:

```
//p would be n x m array

p = new int*[n];
for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    p[i] = new int[m];
}
```